# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, isomorphic-javascript

I am new to isomorphic Javascript, so please bear with. I am using Gulp in conjunction with Babelify, with presets es2015, stage0, and react on an express server.

My component, script.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

export class Son extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Bleh</h3>
        <p>
          Paragraph 1
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Son />,
    document.getElementById('s1')
  );
}
```

My routes, index.js:

```
let React = require('react');
let ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

import Son from '../public/javascripts/script';
// let Son = require('../public/javascripts/script').default;
console.log(Son);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let testString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Son />);

  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Express',
    react: testString
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Gulp and nodemon are both transpiling/compiling fine. The console.log output of `Son` is producing a null object: `{}`. The problem here is the export/import of the module; when I copy and paste the class declaration to the routes module, the output changes to `[Function: Son]` and the app runs as intended. I have read the other posts on how to handle the importation of modules and have tried all the solutions (including conventional es5 syntax of `module.exports =` and `require(...).default`), but none have worked. At any rate, it would be wonderful if I could properly nail this concept using es6.

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting a named export called `Son` instead of making it the default export.

You can either change your export:

```
export default class Son extends React.Component {
```

Or change your import:

```
import { Son } from '../public/javascripts/script';
```

You probably want the former.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but no dice. I ended up doing some testing by trying to require the transpiled module from a test file in the same folder, just to make doubly sure that my paths were correct. I found that the react component constructor did not make the jump, even though all code within it was executed. I ended up rewriting my component in pure es5, having my compiled route file import from that source. Golden. Turns out that the gulp/babel transpile is mangling the export somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's the issue: Browserify was what was messing everything up and preventing export/import. I had to first transpile my component to an intermediate es5 version which I could both require in another module and bundle up with browserify for the front end.

.babelrc file:

```
{ "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"] }
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

watch(['./source/*.js'], function() {
  console.log("App has been modified; re-compiling.");
  gulp.start('default');
});

// bundles front end after react code transpiles.
gulp.task('frontEnd', ['reactStuff'], function() {
  console.log('frontend compiling.');
  return browserify('./experimental/script.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/'));
});

// transpiles react component from jsx and es6 to es5.
gulp.task('reactStuff', function() {
  console.log('react compiling.');
  return gulp.src('./source/script.js')
      .pipe(babel())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./experimental/'));
});

// transpiles routes rendering react components on the server to es5.
gulp.task('routerStuff', function() {
  console.log('routes compiling.');
  return gulp.src('./source/index.js')
      .pipe(babel())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./routes/'));
});

// default task, loops in all other tasks.
gulp.task('default', ['reactStuff', 'routerStuff', 'frontEnd'], function () {
  console.log('done.');
});
```